# Response Functions in a Random Forest

Tags: random-forest

I am reading a chapter about random forest in a textbook. After the section about the predictor importance, the author introduces "Response Functions" as follow:

"Predictor importance is only part of the story. In addition to knowing the
importance of each predictor, it can be very useful to have a description of
how each predictor is related to the response. The set of response functions
needs to be described. For tree-based approaches such as CART, one proceeds
as follows.

1. Grow a forest.
2. Suppose x1 is the initial predictor of interest, and it has *v* distinct values
   in the training data. Construct *v* data sets as follows.

   a) For each of the *v* values of x1, make up a new dataset where x1 only takes on that value, leaving all other variables untouched.

   b) For each of the *v* datasets, predict the response using random forests.There will be a single value averaged over all observations.

   c) Average each of these predictions over the trees.

   d) Plot the average prediction for each value for each of the *v* datasets
   against the *v* values of x1
3. Go back to Step 2 and repeat for each predictor."

I use random forest occasionally, and I understand the basic procedure of the model. But the step 2 b) and 2 c) are confusing to me. 
If we have *N* observations and x1 has *p* unique values, can anyone help to describe how the steps should be done?